# How to clone document to another collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var templateSchema = new Schema ({
    template: {}
});

var selfEvalFormSchema = new Schema ({
    self_EvalForm: {}
});
```

Currently, I'm using MEAN stack to develop my application and use mongoose to connect with the MongoDB. My question is, how to copy or duplicate a document in the `tempalte{}` to the `self_EvalForm{}`

Comment: Oh! thank you so much :D